# Invalid Column Name Exception on Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing

While using Entity Framework and creating my unit tests on most tables, a very peculiar error has occurred on one of them. While adding an entry to the table "Users", I get the error that there is an Invalid Column Name "Setup_Pk". But here's the thing, that field is not specified anywhere in the code. I searched the entire solution and that field was not mentioned anywhere. I accessed the database and the field is also not there on the table "Users". I've already made a few unit tests to other tables, but this one is the only one up to now to have given me this sort of error on a field that I cannot seem to find anywhere. I'd like to know if there is someway I can fix this or if there is something else that I need to check.

Regards

Comment: Is the User table the first table you access? Add also the user class. Setup_Pk could be the primary key to Setup table if you changed the naming convenction (by default it should be Setup_Id).

Comment: What do the models look like (Users, Setup)?

Comment: Thank you, but I figured it out. It was actually my database configuration file that was pointing to an older version of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, but I figured it out. It was actually my database configuration file that was pointing to an older version of the database.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a database trigger that runs on insert.

To test if this is the case try inserting a row directly by running an SQL Statement.

If this does not identify the solution, use the SQL Profiler to check which statements are being sent to the database.